# Formula for producing numbers between 0 and 255?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm writing a program that needs to cycle through numbers between 0-255 given mouse X position. If given number goes over 255, the difference should be subtracted, as in 0,1,2...255,254,253...3,2,1,0,1,2,3,4...255,254...

For example

```
Given  Output
  1      1
  2      2
 255    255
 256    254
 509     0
 510     1
```

I've been toying with different formulas `(x mod 255)` is close but when it goes over 255, goes straight to 0 rather than 254.

Another one I came up with was `round( 127.5*cos(x/16)+127.5 )` it produced [decent numbers](http://codepad.org/eWKt7TWt) but not good enough.

Am I making this too complicated? What is a formula that can produce numbers like this?

Comment: what about using a piecewise function?

Comment: Shouldn't 509 given an output of 1 and 510 give an output of 2?

Comment: fixed thanks. @fvel could you give an example?

Comment: If the output given $255$ is $255$ and you really want to count from $255$ down to $0$ without skipping any numbers, then the output given $509$ is $1$ and the output given $510$ is $0$. See my answer for further details. By the way, since you start counting at $1$ rather than $0,$ some answers appear to assume you want to use the $255$ numbers $1$ through $255$ rather than $256$ numbers $0$ through $255.$

Comment: @KevinDuke The function I gave you satisfy all the examples you cited. In case what you described is not really what you wanted, I think I know what you want and suggest you to try this : 255-abs(($x%510)-255)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a detailed solution which works for $5$ instead of $255$, but I easily extended it to your need at the end.

Let's start with a function $f(x) = x$. For $1$ to $9$ you get :

$1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$

Then with $x-5$, you get :

$-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,4,5$

With $\sqrt{(x-5)^2}$ you get :

$4,3,2,1,0,1,2,3,4$

Then $5-\sqrt{(x-5)^2}$ gives you :

$1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1$.

For $5$, the final formula is $f(x) = 5-\sqrt{(\bmod(x,9)-5)^2}$
For $255$, your final formula is then  $f(x) = 255-\sqrt{(\bmod(x,509)-255)^2}$ !

PS : I saw you using PHP so here's the PHP equivalent :

```
return 255-abs((x%509)-255)
```

Comment: This is wrong (insert values and find out, you'll get sequences like 4,3,2,0,1) and violates the specification. Also, please use the absolute value, e.g. $|x-5|$.

Comment: @GDumphart Fixed thank you

Comment: Yup now it works. Your final line of code seems like the optimal solution.

Comment: Yup, perfect. Also thanks for the explanation! http://codepad.org/UI3vsjQV (for my reference later)

Comment: @Pyrofoux This formula actually seems to skip 1 on the descending count. Look at input 508 and 509 on the codepad link above. It's repeated all descending 1's

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
output = abs(mod(input + 252,508)-253)+1;
```

It works and fulfills all your specifications, I tried it in Matlab.

Comment: This seems to work: http://codepad.org/gsSwf7l1 Thanks!

Comment: Given that the period of the OP's sequence is $510$, I doubt this works, although it's not far. Notice your output can't be $0$. The patch is easy though. In Python,

    **def f(n):
        return abs((n + 254)%510 - 255)**

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut The question asker screwed me by recently editing his question, he initially didn't include $0$s. At the time of the question, my answer was fully compliant with his demands and my code was tested twice. See the comments in the answer of 'fvel'.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see this, ok! +1 then, as it's by far the simplest solution.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut No problem, it's confusing. Thank you for the kind words, but Pyrofoux's final line of code is an even simpler solution :)

Answer (score 3):

I'll define $f(x)$ to be the output of your function given $x.$
That is,
$$\begin{eqnarray}
f(1) &=& 1, \\
f(2) &=& 2, \\
f(255) &=& 255, \\
f(256) &=& 254, \\
\end{eqnarray}$$
and so forth.
I also assume you meant to have $f(0) = 0$ if $0$ is in the domain of your function.

If you continue stepping down from the output $254$ (given $256$) without skipping
any numbers, and you allow the output to go all the way down to $0,$
then adding $1$ to $x$ reduces $f(x)$ by $1,$
adding $2$ to $x$ reduces $f(x)$ by $2,$
and adding $253$ to $x$ reduces $f(x)$ by $253.$
That is,
$$\begin{eqnarray}
f(257) &=& 253, \\
f(258) &=& 252, \\
f(509) &=& 1, \\
f(510) &=& 0, \\
f(511) &=& 1, \\
f(512) &=& 2, \\
\end{eqnarray}$$
and so forth, since you want to start counting upward again once you reach $0.$

It should be clear from this that the period of your function is exactly $510.$
That is, once you reach the output $0,$ it will take $510$ additional steps (incrementing
the given value by $1$ each time) to reach the next output of $0.$

The following function will do the job:

$$f(x) = |((x + 254) \mod 510) - 254|$$

You can test it with the following PHP code:

```
<?
for($x = 0; $x <= 1025; $x++) {
      echo($x . "  ->  " . abs((($x + 254) % 510) - 254)) . "\n";
}
?>
```

Look particularly at the output for inputs near $255,$ near $510,$ near $765,$
and near $1020.$

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can do. Start with the [triangular wave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave#Definitions) using the definition

$$x(t,a) = \frac{2}{a}\left(t-a\left\lfloor\frac{t}{a}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor\right)(-1)^{\left\lfloor\tfrac{t}{a}+\tfrac{1}{2}\right\rfloor}$$

The function you need is

$$y(t,a) = \frac{a}{2}x\left(\frac{t-a/2}{2},\frac{a}{2}\right)+\frac{a}{2}$$

where $a = 255$. This simplifies to

$$y(t,a) = \frac{a}{2}\left(1 - (-1)^{\lfloor t/a \rfloor} \left(1 - 2 \frac{t}{a} + 2  \left\lfloor \frac{t}{a}\right\rfloor\right)\right).$$

Comment: What's with the down-vote?

Answer (score 1):

Look at smaller example, $3$ instead $255$.

```
x = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
v:  1 2 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 2...
```

The smallest period here is `1 2 3 2`. Let $(a_n)_{0..3}$ be 4 element sequence, $(a_n) = (1,2,3,2)$ numbered from zero ($a_0 = 1$). The answer is $f(x) = a_{\left(x-1 \mod 4\right)}$.

Of course, if you don't want to make this sequence in memory, you can make similar function without it. Let $m = 255*2 - 2$.

$$
f(x) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{l l}
    x & x < 255\\
    255 - (x-255) & x \in [255; m] \\
    f((x-1 \mod{m})+1) &  x > m\\
  \end{array} \right.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The graph of the function you desire is a triangle wave as follows:

[image: triangle wave]

To create this function, we can start with a shifted sawtooth wave $x\%255-127.5$ which looks like:

[image: sawtooth]

This when multiplied with $(-1)^{floor(\frac{x}{255})}$ will become:

[image]

Now all that is remaining is to shift the graph up by adding 127.5.

Therefore the final function will be:

$ (x\%255-127.5)(-1)^{floor(\frac{x}{255})}+ 127.5 $

The PHP code for this is:

```
<?
for($x = 1; $x <= 2500; $x++)
{
    echo(  255-abs(($x%509)-255)   ). "\n";
}
?>
```

This function does not skip 1 in descending count from 508 to 509.

Answer (score -1):

As a single function:
$$\mathrm{sgn}\left(\sin(\dfrac{\pi x}{255})\right)x \pmod{255}$$

Or piecewise:
$$*\left\{\begin{matrix}
x \pmod {255} &&&1\leq x\leq 255 \mod (510)\\
-x \pmod {255} &&&256\leq x\leq 510 \mod (510)
\end{matrix}\right.$$

I think these should work.

Comment: The first function won't work as it will have some $0$'s at $255$. Not sure how to improve on that...

Comment: Yeah this is wrong, it's trickier than that.

Comment: @fvel Having 0's are actually ok, I should have mentioned this

Comment: @KevinDuke You specified otherwise though, e.g. with $f(509) = 1$, pff.

Comment: @GDumphart yeah I'm a dunce I was thinking 255 but forgot it's actually 256 numbers including 0. Though in the program being off by 1 isn't important

Comment: I don't have any graphing software, but the first should work with some minor modifications I think. But I see there are already better answers given, so I'll give let this be as it is.